# Find netMask on Android device

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming

I have to find information about the network to which the Android device is connected. Basically the Android device is a Android TV and it has WiFi and Ethernet connectivity.
I am working with WiFi and getting all the correct information except `netMask` as it is always showing **0** (zero), whereas it should show **255.255.255.0**

Following is the code that I'm using:

```
wifiMgr= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
dhcpInfo=wifiMgr.getDhcpInfo();

vDns1="DNS 1: "+intToIp(dhcpInfo.dns1);
vDns2="DNS 2: "+intToIp(dhcpInfo.dns2);
vGateway="Default Gateway: "+intToIp(dhcpInfo.gateway);
vIpAddress="IP Address: "+intToIp(dhcpInfo.ipAddress);
vLeaseDuration="Lease Time: "+String.valueOf(dhcpInfo.leaseDuration);
vNetmask="Subnet Mask: "+intToIp(dhcpInfo.netmask);
vServerAddress="Server IP: "+intToIp(dhcpInfo.serverAddress);
```

Definition for `intToIp(int)`:

```
public String intToIp(int i) {

    return ((i >> 24 ) & 0xFF ) + "." +
            ((i >> 16 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
            ((i >> 8 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
            ( i & 0xFF) ;
}
```

The `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [an android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82477).

According to the bug report, you can either use the following workaround (copied from the report):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
DhcpInfo dhcpInfo = wifiManager.getDhcpInfo();
try {
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(extractBytes(dhcpInfo.ipAddress));
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(inetAddress);
    for (InterfaceAddress address : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
        //short netPrefix = address.getNetworkPrefixLength();
        Log.d(TAG, address.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

... or stop using this API altogether and use the [LinkProperties](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getLinkProperties(android.net.Network)) API instead.

Comment: Tried the code, it gives exception IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Address is neither 4 or 16 bytes: [-64], why -64 ?

Comment: LinkProperties.getRoutes() gives [fe80::/64 -> :: wlan0,192.168.43.0/24 -> 0.0.0.0 wlan0,0.0.0.0/0 -> 192.168.43.1 wlan0,];

Comment: That's the interface's [routing table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table). It tells you that the interface is connected directly to the network `192.168.43.0/24` which means that the network address is `192.168.43.0` with a netmask of `255.255.255.0` (24 x `1` bits). And the gateway to exit the network (the router that connects the network to the rest of the Internet) is at 192.168.43.1